# Reputation for Editing Posts

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation

I have a question about gaining reputation from editing post. I know there is a description, but it is not clear to me (maybe because English is not my native language).

The description for editing reputation says:

> You gain reputation when: suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000
>   total per user).

Does this mean:

1. I get altogether 1,000 points for 500 edited posts (beside upvotes and other rep)?
2. Or do I stop gaining reputation from editing when I reach the 1,000 rep mark?

Comment: It is 1) You get altogether 1000 points for 500 edited posts

Comment: You also stop getting rep from edits if you have 2000 total rep, regardless of ho much of that 2k is from edits.

Comment: @Cerbrus you still get 2 rep per accepted edit-suggestion when you are above 2000 rep - but you can only suggest tag-wiki edits then, since all others are applied directly.